# Spark: conditional (`if`) to pass parameter value to a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to pass a parameter value to a function but evaluating the value of another variable. I've tried this:

```
val myRDDResult = myRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex( myFunction(index, partData, if (limit > partData.size) limit else limit - 1 ), preservesPartitioning = true)
```

But doesn't work. And I also checked doing this:

```
val myRDDResult = myRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex( myFunction(index, partData, limit ), preservesPartitioning = true)
```

And this works! So I think the problem is using the `if` inside, but I don't know how can I make it.